# UIWebview with PDF (wrong Colors)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf, colors, uiwebview

I'm having a PDF which looks perfectly in SnowLepard Preview but when i'm loading the same PDF in a WebView, the pdf won't show the right colors.
My first idea was a RGB/CMYK problem, but i'm stuck.

**What pdf-format is the best for iOS ?**

[image]
cheers
endo

Comment: Could you post a screenshot so we can see the differences?

Comment: With respect to your first idea, did you try outputting in RGB? The boilerplate answer for this sort of query tends to be 'the iPad displays CMYK very poorly, avoid it', but it sounds like you may already have investigated that avenue?

Comment: Might have something to do with the source of the PDF...did you create it or download it?

Comment: Why are you stuck. You'r first idea is probably the good one.

Answer (score 6):

That is most certainly because your pdf is using color palette other than RGB (CYMK probably).  Try re creating your pdf with RGB Profile.